# How to convert this DateTime so it looks good in Angular Material <mat-card-subtitle>

Tags: angular, visual-studio, datetime

I have this date that looks like this

> 2000-12-16T00:00:00

when I show it in this Material code:(it´s the publish_date)

```
<mat-card *ngFor="let book of bookItems">

  <mat-card-header >
    <mat-card-title>{{book.title | titlecase}}</mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-subtitle>{{book.description}}</mat-card-subtitle>
    <mat-card-subtitle>{{book.author}}</mat-card-subtitle>
    <mat-card-subtitle>{{book.genre}}</mat-card-subtitle>
    <mat-card-subtitle>{{book.publish_date}}</mat-card-subtitle>
    <mat-card-subtitle>{{book.price}}</mat-card-subtitle>

  </mat-card-header>

</mat-card>
```

How do I convert it into something nicer more human friendly?

The date comes from an xml file like:

```
  <book id="B1">
    <author>Kutner, Joe</author>
    <title>Deploying with JRuby</title>
    <genre>Computer</genre>
    <price>33.00</price>
    <publish_date>2012-08-15</publish_date>
    <description>Deploying with JRuby is the missing link between enjoying JRuby and using it in the real world to build high-performance, scalable applications.</description>
  </book>
```

and it is read in like this:(it´s the Publish_date )

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetBookItems()
{
    List<BookItem> BookItems = new List<BookItem>();
    XDocument doc = _db.GetXmlDb();
    List<BookItem> bookitems = doc.Descendants("book").Select(x => new BookItem()
    {
        Id = (string)x.Attribute("id"),
        Author = (string)x.Element("author"),
        Title = (string)x.Element("title"),
        Genre = (string)x.Element("genre"),
        Price = (decimal)x.Element("price"),
        Publish_date = (DateTime)x.Element("publish_date"),
        Description = (string)x.Element("description")
    }).ToList();
    return Ok(bookitems);
}
```

This is basically a Crud call from the Angular app and the code above is the ASP.NET `Controller`

How can I when I receive the `bookItem` in the Angular app make it nicer.
This is the Angular app book

```
export interface BookItem
{
  id: string;
  author: string;
  title: string;
  genre: string;
  price: string;
  publish_date: string;
  description: string;

}
```

Comment: when you receive the `bookItem` in angular convert it to a javascript Date object. then use angular date pipe https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe in your template to display it in a more friendly format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Angular's [DatePipes](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) to transform that date value into your required date string.

But first, you should convert it into a Date object by doing something similar to this:

```
new Date('2000-12-16T00:00:00');
```

Then, on your `<mat-card-subtitle>` that requires the usage of the `DatePipe`, you can either use the [pre-defined formats](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#pre-defined-format-options)

```
<mat-card-subtitle>{{ book.publish_date | date: long }}</mat-card-subtitle>
```

Or supply the pipe with your own [custom format](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#custom-format-options).

```
<mat-card-subtitle>{{book.publish_date | date: 'dd MMMM yyyy' }}</mat-card-subtitle>
```

Comment: Thanks, Perfect question give perfect answer